# CreateService or StartService hangs on windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, winapi, service, windows-7, windows-7-x64

CreateService or StartService hangs on windows 7 x64 when i trying to use it to register new service from service.
In service control manager my service, which i try to run, has status 'Starting'.

Code that try to create and run service:

```
SC_HANDLE hSCManager = ::OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
if(!hSCManager)
    throw ::GetLastError();
SC_HANDLE hService = ::OpenService(hSCManager,
                                       TEXT("ProcessManager"),
                                       SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);

if(!hService && ::GetLastError() == ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST)
{
    hService = ::CreateService(hSCManager, TEXT("ProcessManager"),
        TEXT("ProcessManager"), SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER,
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START, SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE, TEXT("C:\\processmanager.sys"),
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

if(!hService ||
    (!::StartService(hService, 0, NULL) && ::GetLastError() != ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING))
{
    ::CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
    if(hService)
        ::CloseServiceHandle(hService);
    DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
    throw err;
}
```

Please help :)

Comment: Would love to help, but there's not enough information.

Comment: This is code that try to run service:

Comment: So, what is `C:\\processmanager.sys`? And I trust the code in the Q runs elevated. How far into that code does it reach? It hangs in `CreateService`?

Comment: C:\\processmanager.sys it's a driver, that can intercept process. This code run in ServiceMain function. If i'm trying to run this code into usually user application nor service, it worked.

Comment: I cannot understand that comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the key information is that the code is running in a ServiceMain function.  See my answer. :-)

Comment: @Harry Well done. +1. I'm glad you could work it out. Was beyond my little brain.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation for ServiceMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Do not attempt to start another service in the ServiceMain function.

and

> The SCM locks the service control database during initialization, so if a service attempts to call StartService during initialization, the call will block. When the service reports to the SCM that it has successfully started, it can call StartService. If the service requires another service to be running, the service should set the required dependencies.

So, there's your problem: your program is deadlocking because it is calling `StartService` while the service control database is locked.  (Actually, it is probably deadlocking on the `CreateService` call first; the documentation doesn't explicitly mention it, but the same restriction applies there too.)

Install the device driver at the same time that you install your service, rather than trying to install it from your service.